# Problems with PHP variables in the URL of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using the following script to use a popup window to load a $_GET address:

```
while ($row1 = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($_SESSION['scontact_id'] == 'scontact_id' && $row1['shared_id'] != '' && $row1['shared_id'] != '0'){
        echo "<td> <center><button onclick='myFunction()'><img border='0' alt='Contacts' src='/Welcome/modules/mod_crmsearch/images/peoplesmall.png'></button></center>
            <script>
                function myFunction(shared_id) {
                window.open('". $mywebsite . "vcontact_id=" . $row1['shared_id'] ."' +shared_id, '_blank', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400');
                }
            </script> </td>";
```

However, it only loads the first row in the loop correctly. After that, it displays the same $_GET address, regardless of where it is in the while loop. It does the same thing if I convert the row to a php variable and pass the PHP variable, to the script, as a JavaScript variable. It works fine, without the popup, like this:

```
echo "<td>"."<a href='" . $mywebsite . "vcontact_id=" . $row1['shared_id'] . "' target='_blank', '_blank', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400'><center><img border='0' alt='Contacts' src='/Welcome/modules/mod_crmsearch/images/peoplesmall.png'></center></a>" . "</td>";
```

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<button>` by default (without specifying `type` attribute) is a submit button. It will fire submit action, unless you use `event.preventDefault();` to stop the default action. Also, your HTML codes have problems. Time to learn up-to-date syntax.

Comment: I see your problem is that there's only one myFunction and the value will depends on your last result

Comment: @NewbeeDev thanks for pointing that out, its also the flaw in most of the answers below.

Comment: so you miss to pass the parameter in your function that's all

Comment: Well I am not the OP who posted the question, and I believe the script needs moved outside the if loop, but your comment helped me present an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chage this part:

```
echo "<td> <center><button onclick='myFunction()'>
```

for this:

```
echo "<td> <center><button onclick='myFunction(\"" . $row1['shared_id'] . "\")'>
```

EDIT: Or make it one line instead of using a function:

```
echo "<td> <center><button onclick='window.open(\"". $mywebsite . "vcontact_id=" . $row1['shared_id'] ."\", \"_blank\", \"toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400\");'><img border='0' alt='Contacts' src='/Welcome/modules/mod_crmsearch/images/peoplesmall.png'></button></center></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

myFunction is being overwritten each time in the loop. You could always rewrite the code with an increment counter to change the function name. It's typically better to not mix javascript in php in my opinion. You could always just pass these in as additional parameters into your function where you are outputting php / js.

Answer (score 1):

You are continuously redefining the function: `myFunction()`. you should output the script tag once, outside the loop, and change the onclick attribute on your button to `...<button onclick='myFunction(" . $row1['shared_id']  . ")'>...`, if I am reading your problem correctly

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
<?php
while ($row1 = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($_SESSION['scontact_id'] == 'scontact_id' && $row1['shared_id'] != '' && $row1['shared_id'] != '0'){
        echo "<td> <center><button onclick='myFunction(".$row1['shared_id'].")'><img border='0' alt='Contacts' src='/Welcome/modules/mod_crmsearch/images/peoplesmall.png'></button></center></td>";
    }
}
?>
<script>
var mywebsite = "<?php echo $mywebsite ?>";
function myFunction(shared_id) {
window.open(mywebsite+"vcontact_id="+shared_id, '_blank', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you simply need to move your script outside the if loop, yet maintain it in the while loop and you need to add your (shared_id) that is required by the function, to the click event.

```
<?php
while ($row1 = $sth1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($_SESSION['scontact_id'] == 'scontact_id' && $row1['shared_id'] != '' && $row1['shared_id'] != '0'){
        echo "<td> <center><button onclick='myFunction(".$row1['shared_id'].")'><img border='0' alt='Contacts' src='/Welcome/modules/mod_crmsearch/images/peoplesmall.png'></button></center></td>";
    }
echo "
    <script>
    function myFunction(shared_id) {
        window.open('". $mywebsite . "vcontact_id=" . $row1['shared_id'] ."' +shared_id, '_blank', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400');
    }
    </script>  
";
}
```

If you care at all about page optimization, it would be far wiser instead of looping the script in the while statement, to set a data variable and a class on the button and use an onclick event to determine the values so you don't have 20 instances of the same script with different values on the page.

For example:

Inside your button:

```
class='clicked' data-id='".$row1['shared_id']."'
```

Then use jquery for the script

```
<script>
    $( ".clicked" ).click(function() {
        var data = $(this).attr('data-id');
        window.open('". $mywebsite . "vcontact_id='+data', '_blank', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=500,width=400,height=400');
    }
</script>
```

This looks for a click event on the class "clicked" which we assigned to the button. When button is clicked, we get the value of "data-id" and set it as a variable "data". We then call that variable instead of echoing a php variable. This allows us to take the script out of the loop and not write it to the page multiple times.

Comment: I opted to offer this solution because everyone else is recommending you remove the entire script from the loop altogether, which I believe will return an improper result depending on usage. If the value of the $row1 changes in the while loop, and the script is written outside the while loop, it will only return the last iteration of the loop. My way, the script is written in the while loop so if multiple $row1 results are echoed on the same page, the script will always display those results which each change. Otherwise it will only output the values of the last $row1 value.